# How to generate the HashKey from command line for SMS Retriver api

Tags: android, api, hash, sms

I am trying to use the SMS Retriver API suggested by google.
The code worked when i used the [java Helper Class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java) to generate the HashKey.

The Broadcast was detected properly.
But When i used the [Keytool command suggested here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string)

i get a different hashkey and it does not work either.

Note. 
I have executed the command from gitbash and windows command prompt
the generated hashkey is the same.

UPDATE

So Far After some tests i have only managed to confirm one thing

The HashKey generated for a locally installed apk either by debug or by copying the signed apk to device **IS DIFFERENT** than the one generated after it is uploaded to playstore.

On top of this i am still not able to use the keytool command to generate the Hashkey. The command fails near the pipelining of echo statement.

Has anyone managed to generate the hashkey from command line.

Any suggestions are appriciated.

Comment: You will have to put your Keystore and Password File>Project Structure>app>Signing here and then You will have to go Gradle>app>android>signingReport on the topmost right side. After a process, you will get both debug and release SH1.

Comment: @RakeshKumar I am not look for the sha-1 finger print. I am trying to implement the automatic sms verification as shown in the links provided above.

Comment: It will not work because the device will multiple SMS app like hangout, Default SMS and some other App which becomes default will prevent to do that.

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar  Just to clarify  i am not using the READ_SMS or SMS_RECEIVED actions. What i am trying to use is the SMS_RETRIEVED action for otp only.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview